# Are there thunderstorms in Minecraft: XBox 360 Edition?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Do [thunderstorms](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Thunderstorm) take place in Minecraft: XBox 360 Edition?

I have heard they do, and I seem to recall seeing a loading screen tip about lightning hitting mobs, but I have never seen one, and my online research seems inconclusive.

If they do occur, how do you tell them apart from normal rain? I have heard they are darker, but is it very noticeable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Xbox 360 version](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Xbox_360_Edition) is at PC patch Beta 1.6.6. [Weather](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Weather) was introduced in Beta 1.5.

So yes, there is thunderstorms and all types of weather in the Xbox 360 version.

Bonus: Crappy video of weather in action:

Comment: +1 the reply, but does this video show a thunderstorm? It looks like normal rain. I haven't seen lightning or heard thunder or lightning in Minecraft on XBox. Perhaps weather was added in 1.5 but thunderstorms were added later?

Comment: @Wikwocket Thunderstorms were added in the same patch, however are rare compared to normal rain.

Comment: Update: I was on XBox last night and I heard some thunder during a rainstorm. It was a very distinct sound effect (and it wasn't a creeper since it was on Peaceful), so I'm calling that proof positive and accepting this answer! :)